# NSAttributedString: How do you add BOLD to a customized (e.g., Palatino) font?

Tags: swift, fonts, nsattributedstring

Below are some customized extension functions for the NSAttributedString class for the Palatino font:

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    class func blueAttributeStringOf(string:NSString) -> NSAttributedString {
        let dict = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Palatino", size: 14.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:blissBlue]
        let attrString = NSAttributedString(string:string as String, attributes: dict)
        return attrString
    }

    class func standardAttributeStringOf(string:String) -> NSAttributedString {
        let dict = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Palatino", size: 14.0)!]
        let attrString = NSAttributedString(string:string as String, attributes: dict)
        return attrString
    }
}
```

I can't find the **bold** attribute for the NSAttributedString class.  How do I add the **bold** attribute to any particular font (e.g., the Palatino font)?

Comment: You do have ["`Palatino-Bold`" as a font you can work with](http://iosfonts.com/), b.t.w.

Comment: "Bold Attribute" is inside the Font Attribute. The font has to be bold. It's not like Photoshop where you can add a fake bold effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bold a string without changing its other attributes by setting the `StrokeWidth` attribute with a *negative* value.

```
let attrString = NSAttributedString(string: string as String, attributes: [.strokeWidth: NSNumber(value: -3.0)])
```